# How to turn on LoudSpeaker Mode in Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am planning to put the device in loudspeaker mode from my win phone application. (Like on click of some button)
Are there any APIs or workarounds to do so on Windows Phone 7.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API available to control a loud speaker or speaker phone mode.

You can only control the relative volume of any sound you're directly playing.